# A name for the "correlation" of three variables?

Tags: correlation, terminology, association-measure

I have three signals and I want to get some measure of the 'linear together-ness' between them. If they are all high or all low at the same time, that is good; if two are high and one is low that's not as good, if one is high and one is low and one is in the center that's not good at all.

The first two measures I explored to capture this are linear functions of each other, one being the mean between each of the 3 pairwise correlations and the second being the proportion of "variance" captured in the (1,1,1) direction. **Is there a name (and preferably a paper citation) for either kind of measure?**

More explicitly, let the signals be denoted as $\hat{x}_i, \hat{y}_i, \hat{z}_i, 1 \leq i \leq N,$ such that each has $\mu=0, \sigma^2=1$. The first measure is the average of the Pearson correlation between $X$ and $Y$, $Y$ and $Z$, and $X$ and $Z$, calculated as $$\frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_i\hat{x}_i\hat{y}_i+\frac{1}{N}\sum_i\hat{y}_i\hat{z}_i+\frac{1}{N}\sum_i\hat{x}_i\hat{z}_i}{3}$$.

The second measure is calculating the ratio between the expected squared distance from the mean when all points are projected onto the line defined by $(t,t,t), t\in\mathbb{R}$ and the expected squared distance from the mean without that projection, calculated as $$\frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}(\hat{x}_i+\hat{y}_i+\hat{z}_i)^2}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_i(\hat{x}_i^2+\hat{y}_i^2+\hat{z}_i^2)}$$.

It is not difficult to show they are linearly equivalent - multiple out the square in the numerator of the second measure and use the fact that we've already normalized the signals to replace $\sum_i\hat{x}_i^2 = 1$.

**Is there a name for this measure?** I'm pretty sure I'm not the first to need to get the linear-together-ness of three signals, but the lack of answers to similar questions makes me wonder if it's at all popular.

Comment: This is interesting, I myself always resorted to PCA for this. The shared variance of the three variables is measured in fact by the biggest eigenvalue of their correlation matrix.

Comment: @Carlo You seem to conflate *variance* and *correlation,* but these quantities, although related, are distinct.

Comment: correlation matrix is the covariance matrix of scaled dataset, I wasn't confused.

Comment: No, I can actually see were I misspoke: I meant *the proportion of variance* which is shared

Comment: Whait, my comment is not precise, I don't remember now what is the right way to do it, I think really was confused.

Comment: @carlo It is also the case that sampling error between both *variables* and latent *components* biases calculated eigenvalues w/r/t the amount of variance explained towards the earlier (i.e. larger eigenvalues). For example, if for data generated by trule uncorrelated processes, some eigenvalues will seem to be larger than others, with the ratio between the number of variable and the sample size influencing this bias. Likewise, for $m$ number of true components contributing equally to observed variables, the first $m$ eigenvalues will appear to be unequal in size.

Comment: $1/N$ times the largest eigenvalue of the correlation matrix answers to all your requirements. In the case $N=2$ with correlation coefficient $\rho$ this equals $\left(1+\rho\right)/2.$ See our threads on PCA for more.